# PHP OOP error that I cannot understand

Tags: php, oop

I try to extend the CheckfrontAPI class with my new class.

In my case I use the Singleton pattern in order to load only one instance at a time of my class and I get that error

Fatal error: Declaration of CheckFrontIntegrator::store() must be compatible with that of CheckfrontAPI::store() in /home/my_web_site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/checkfront/class/Checkfront_Integration.php on line 83

Any idea on how to solve that issue ?

Here is the CheckfrontAPI source code : https://github.com/Checkfront/PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/CheckfrontAPI.php

And here is my class that extends that class:

```
<?php

class CheckFrontIntegrator extends CheckfrontAPI
{
    private static $instance = null;
    public $tmp_file = '.checkfront_oauth';

    final protected function store($data = array())
    {
        $tmp_file = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $this->tmp_file;

        if(count($data))
        {
            file_put_contents(  
                $tmp_file,
                json_encode(
                    $data, 
                    true
                )
            );
        }
        elseif(is_file($tmp_file))
        {
            $data = json_decode(
                trim(
                    file_get_contents(
                        $tmp_file
                    )
                ),
                true
            );
        }

        return $data;
}

    public function session($session_id, $data = array())
    {
        $_SESSION['checkfront']['session_id'] = $session_id;
}

    public static function instance($data)
    {
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new CheckFrontIntegrator($data);
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        if(session_id() == '')
        {
            session_start();
        }

        parent::__construct($data, session_id());
    }
}

?>
```

And I initiate the new instance of that class like that:

```
$this->checkfront_integrator = CheckFrontIntegrator::instance($args);
```

where args are all the important information needit by the class to initiate a new object

AFTER EDIT

I have change my method store from:

```
final protected function store($data = array())
....
```

to

```
protected function store($data)
....
```

and the problem still occure :(

Comment: Do the number and types of parameters match?  (Between both `store()` member functions.)

Comment: can you paste the full error you are getting after modification

Comment: Your method store should look like: protected function store($data)! You already solve the problem by yoursefl with method session. In your class:  public function session($session_id, $data = array()), int the class you extend from: abstract public function session($session_id,$data);

Comment: This is my new error: Fatal error: Declaration of CheckFrontIntegrator::session() must be compatible with that of CheckfrontAPI::session() in /home/my_server/public_html/wp-content/plugins/checkfront/class/Checkfront_Integration.php on line 83

Comment: @ab_dev86 As you see, I have made the modification of the method signature, but the problem is still there .... :( Also, I changed the functions order into my file and now the session is the one that make the problem

Comment: @Merianos Nikos. Actually i run your code whithout errors. I'am sospicius about how you instantiate your class: $this->checkfront_integrator = CheckFrontIntegrator::instance($args); what is the preciding code? which object is $this?

Comment: @ab_dev86 The problem solved. Was __cache__ issue. Also in my local web server the code run with no issue. But on HostGator servers I had the issue. Thanks a lot for your assistance and you time !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CheckfrontAPI is an abstract class? in this case your CheckFrontIntegrator::store() arguments count must be identical to original declaration

EDIT

I see on github

```
abstract protected function store($data);
```

your override must be:

```
protected function store($data) {

}
```

Comment: I made that change and the problem still occure. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you some cache somewhere?

Comment: Ok note that also final protected function store($data = array()) is legal!

Answer (score 2):

You are extending CheckfrontAPI. CheckfrontAPI has a method store(). If you override that method you must do it properly.

Post the code of CheckfrontAPI and your class Checkfront_Integration: when can understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to extent the functionality of an existing class by writing your own class and the class you are extending is is an *abstract* one, you'll need to make sure that the function calls are compatible.
What does this mean?

If the class you are extending has this function call for example :

```
function walk($direction, $speed = null);
```

Then you will have to honor the function signature in *your implementation* - that means you'll still have to have to pass two function arguments in your version.

You will **not** be able to alter is to be like this :

```
function walk($direction, $speed, $clothing);
```

Comment: I know that, but if you see my code above, I have the store method in my class with excact arguments, and still get that error :(